# Spark structed streaming window issue

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have a problem regrading the window in Spark Structed Streaming. I want to group the data i'm receiving continuously from kafka source in sliding window and count the number of data. The issue is that writestream streams the window dataframe each time there is data coming and update the count of the current window.

I'm using the following code to create the window:

```
#Define schema of the topic to be consumed 
jsonSchema = StructType([ StructField("State", StringType(), True) \
                        , StructField("Value", StringType(), True) \
                        , StructField("SourceTimestamp", StringType(), True) \
                        , StructField("Tag", StringType(), True)
                        ])


spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("StructuredStreaming") \
    .config("spark.default.parallelism", "100") \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "10.129.140.23:9092") \
  .option("subscribe", "SIMULATOR.SUPERMAN.TOTO") \
  .load() \
  .select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"), jsonSchema).alias("data")) \
  .select("data.*")

df = df.withColumn("time", current_timestamp())

Window = df \
    .withColumn("window",window("time","4 seconds","1 seconds")).groupBy("window").count() \
    .withColumn("time", current_timestamp())

#Write back to kafka

query = Window.select(to_json(struct("count","window","time")).alias("value")) \
    .writeStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "10.129.140.23:9092") \
    .outputMode("update") \
    .option("topic", "structed") \
    .option("checkpointLocation", "/home/superman/notebook/checkpoint") \
    .start()
```

The windows are not sorted and are updated each time there is a change in count. How can we wait for the end of the window and stream the final count one time. Instead of this output:

```
{"count":21,"window":{"start":"2019-05-13T09:39:14.000Z","end":"2019-05-13T09:39:18.000Z"},"time":"2019-05-13T09:39:15.026Z"}
{"count":47,"window":{"start":"2019-05-13T09:39:12.000Z","end":"2019-05-13T09:39:16.000Z"},"time":"2019-05-13T09:39:15.026Z"}
{"count":21,"window":{"start":"2019-05-13T09:39:13.000Z","end":"2019-05-13T09:39:17.000Z"},"time":"2019-05-13T09:39:15.026Z"}
{"count":21,"window":{"start":"2019-05-13T09:39:15.000Z","end":"2019-05-13T09:39:19.000Z"},"time":"2019-05-13T09:39:15.026Z"}
{"count":21,"window":{"start":"2019-05-13T09:39:16.000Z","end":"2019-05-13T09:39:20.000Z"},"time":"2019-05-13T09:39:17.460Z"}
{"count":42,"window":{"start":"2019-05-13T09:39:14.000Z","end":"2019-05-13T09:39:18.000Z"},"time":"2019-05-13T09:39:17.460Z"}
{"count":42,"window":{"start":"2019-05-13T09:39:15.000Z","end":"2019-05-13T09:39:19.000Z"},"time":"2019-05-13T09:39:17.460Z"}
{"count":21,"window":{"start":"2019-05-13T09:39:17.000Z","end":"2019-05-13T09:39:21.000Z"},"time":"2019-05-13T09:39:17.460Z"}
{"count":40,"window":{"start":"2019-05-13T09:39:16.000Z","end":"2019-05-13T09:39:20.000Z"},"time":"2019-05-13T09:39:19.818Z"}
{"count":19,"window":{"start":"2019-05-13T09:39:19.000Z","end":"2019-05-13T09:39:23.000Z"},"time":"2019-05-13T09:39:19.818Z"}
{"count":19,"window":{"start":"2019-05-13T09:39:18.000Z","end":"2019-05-13T09:39:22.000Z"},"time":"2019-05-13T09:39:19.818Z"}
{"count":40,"window":{"start":"2019-05-13T09:39:17.000Z","end":"2019-05-13T09:39:21.000Z"},"time":"2019-05-13T09:39:19.818Z"}
{"count":37,"window":{"start":"2019-05-13T09:39:19.000Z","end":"2019-05-13T09:39:23.000Z"},"time":"2019-05-13T09:39:21.939Z"}
{"count":18,"window":{"start":"2019-05-13T09:39:21.000Z","end":"2019-05-13T09:39:25.000Z"},"time":"2019-05-13T09:39:21.939Z"}
```

I would like this:

```
{"count":47,"window":{"start":"2019-05-13T09:39:12.000Z","end":"2019-05-13T09:39:16.000Z"},"time":"2019-05-13T09:39:15.026Z"}
{"count":21,"window":{"start":"2019-05-13T09:39:13.000Z","end":"2019-05-13T09:39:17.000Z"},"time":"2019-05-13T09:39:15.026Z"}
{"count":42,"window":{"start":"2019-05-13T09:39:14.000Z","end":"2019-05-13T09:39:18.000Z"},"time":"2019-05-13T09:39:17.460Z"}
{"count":42,"window":{"start":"2019-05-13T09:39:15.000Z","end":"2019-05-13T09:39:19.000Z"},"time":"2019-05-13T09:39:17.460Z"}
{"count":40,"window":{"start":"2019-05-13T09:39:16.000Z","end":"2019-05-13T09:39:20.000Z"},"time":"2019-05-13T09:39:19.818Z"}
{"count":40,"window":{"start":"2019-05-13T09:39:17.000Z","end":"2019-05-13T09:39:21.000Z"},"time":"2019-05-13T09:39:19.818Z"}
```

The expected ouput wait for the window to be closed based on comparaison between the end timestamp and the current time.

Comment: I would think that `append` output mode instead of update should do what you want to achieve. But I'm currently unsure if I understood the concept of `append` mode correctly - I'm fighting with it myself

Comment: Sorry for being late. I tried your approach but it gives me the following error:
```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o140.start.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Append output mode not supported when there are streaming aggregations on streaming DataFrames/DataSets without watermark;;
```

Comment: Yes, to use append mode you also need to define watermarks (withWatermark) on your incoming streams. So `df = df.withColumn("time", current_timestamp()).withWatermark("time", "1 minutes"` could be a start. Keep in mind that this means your groupBy will not output any results until that watermark has expired.

Comment: I tried that and it's working like a charm. Thank you so much :)